# Integrating Redis with DataMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, datamapper

I have been using DataMapper as ORM in my Rails application. Here as part of this I have used a model named Student which is written in Datamapper. I am absolute beginner in Redis. I have been studying about how to integrate DataMapper with Redis, I found out one gem **dm-redis-adapter**. I followed the instruction as said in https://github.com/whoahbot/dm-redis-adapter/.

First I was trying in Rails console. So first I set up the DataMapper as follows:

```
 DataMapper.setup(:default, {:adapter  => "redis"})
```

Then while I tried with the statement in Rails console

```
  Student.all.size
```

It is giving me 0 even if there are total 10,000 students in my database in mysql. So I think this is because of the fact that I have not pushed the data to Redis. I have no idea how to do that. So if anyone helps me to figure it out, I will be really grateful. Thanks in advance.